# # of even natural numbers less then or equal to $10^{10}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many natural numbers less than or equal to $10^{10}$ have at least one even digit in their decimal representation?

Is it $10^{10} - 5^{10}$ since there are 10^10 numbers overall and 5^10 odd numbers ? I think I am missing something, but I am not sure?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the complement of what we are trying to find is the number of natural numbers containing only odd numbers. This is significantly easier to find.

To make all the digits odd:

- The first digit can take one possible value ($1$)
- The next ten can take 5 possible values ($1, 3, 5, 7, 9$)

This gives $1\cdot5^{10}=5^{10}$ numbers with all digits odd. The original problem was the complement of this so calculating $10^{10}-5^{10}$ gives an answer of $5^{10}$.